# Will Old revision google play services work after August 1 2014?

Tags: android, admob

What if i have already in my app with ADmob google play service lib(revision 15) do i need to upgrade to new revision(18) or it will be ok on August 1 2014(when google shut down 6.4.1 Ads SDK and lower) ? This upgrade does not cover old revision i hope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. If already your app is showing ads using old play service sdk you can continue with that..or you can upgrade to new one(not required) !